Ruby application deployed on Ubuntu 18, with issues with passenger and apache
This is what I have, how can I fix it? I have to say that I am using Apache to host my website, and I uninstalled them and installed Passenger but the error persists, what can I do? Or if the error is not resolved, what can it affect?
root@inadesvr:/home/servidor# sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Wed Dec 11 08:38:41.964778 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 416:tid 140074950024128] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.0.30 OpenSSL/1.1.1 mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 11 08:38:41.964799 2024] [core:notice] [pid 416:tid 140074950024128] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[ 2024-12-11 08:38:41.9918 386/7f740f013f00 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:967 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
App 529 stdout: 
App 529 stderr: /usr/bin/passenger-config:27:in require'
App 529 stderr: : cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger (LoadError)
App 529 stderr:     from /usr/bin/passenger-config:27:in <main>'
App 545 stdout:
root@inadesvr:/home/servidor# passenger-status
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it is running, then the causes of this problem could be:

1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory and run passenger-status again.
2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument.


you should start here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
